# Parallelization in Durable Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I'm trying to understand how parallelization works in Durable Function. I have a durable function where I first get a list of items and then all items should run in parallel. Meaning the time taken to execute 10 items and 10000 items should be the same? How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches that are possible. The first is to use a suborchestrator for each job so that each suborchestrator handles just a specific job. Here is the docs for this approach https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-sub-orchestrations?tabs=csharp
Example from docs seem to be alike to yours.

The other is to use ContinueWith so that each job has its own "chain"

```cs
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var job in jobs){
   tasks.Add(context.CallActivityAsync<Group>(nameof(GroupNameReaderFunction), job)
        .ContinueWith(prevTask => emailTasks.Add(context.CallActivityAsync(nameof(EmailSenderFunction), prevTask.Result))));
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please answer my question in UPDATED section? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it looks about right. In theory, it will process everything in parallel. Just as a note is that there obviously is a limit to the time it takes to scale out and you may have a maximum of 200 instances (but each may have multiple cores). But it will atleast significantly reduce the total time.

Comment: Thank you - could you please help me understand what do you mean by ‘ time it takes to scale out and you may have a maximum of 200 instances’? I use consumption plan where time limit is 10 min. I need all jobs to complete in 10 min. Could that be possible? Please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: I prolonged my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67997572/use-suborchestratorfunction with some examples that might affect things these may answer some questions. 200 instances meaning the maximum amount of VM s running your task, lo. Estimating if you can complete in 10 minutes is very hard without knowing the exact details of each activity and what services they are using. To ensure many VMs are running use appinsights live metrics.

Comment: Found this. Going from 10000 in 10 minutes to 500000 in 3minutes is quite a big leap but it was interesting to read a massive scale scenario https://madeofstrings.com/2019/01/09/scaling-azure-functions-to-make-500000-requests-to-weather-com-in-under-3-minutes/